# Library to create print-ready charts in PDF using PHP 5.3

Tags: php, charts, tcpdf

I have to create some nicely formatted charts (bar and 3D pie) from dynamic data using PHP 5.3 and for output as PDF report. The report is **not** to be rendered to the screen at all.  I have made the charts using pChart2 as .png files and imported them using tcpdf.  The system works, but the quality level is poor, rendering text as a graphic causes the font edges to be blurry etc. when printed.  I tweaked the image size of the .PNG output, and it made some improvements but it increases the file size, and the text still looks blurry.
So what I am after is a library to create charts using PHP that can be exported to .svg or .eps format, so elements are drawn by the printer and render sharply for print.  Using TCPDF I have imported our logos that are in .EPS format, and the difference between the images is quite marked.

I have seen there is a library called [ezcomponents](http://ezcomponents.org/docs/api/trunk/Graph_gallery.html) that i can give a try.  But before I dive in, is there any advice on what to try before proceeding?

Answer (score 0):

I have had reasonable success rendering the images on a canvas that is two to three times larger than what I ultimately need and then, once I'm finished, using the `imagecopyrresampled()` function to copy the large image onto a canvas with smaller dimensions, which I save as a png and add to the PDF file. The dithering is pretty good and curved lines, in particular, benefit greatly from this approach. Text might not benefit quite as much, but its worth trying, because it should require very few changes to your code to experiment with this approach.

Comment: Hi James. thanks for replying.  I found that rendering the image so the final size was 300dpi gave good enough quality, but then TCPDF was very slow to make the PDF  (> 3 minutes)  I had it automatically calculating the width from a given height of image.  I found that if I set the width and height explicitly the entire render then took 25 seconds.  Additionally i removed the large text on the graph (eg title etc), and rendered that directly onto the graph page using the TCPDF library, so the text rendered clearly.

Comment: That's a good piece of info about explicitly including the width and height of the image. And good thinking to render the text over the top. Nice work!